# how to run Pester quickly with -OutPut Detailed in VSCode?

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, pester

Press the shortcut key 'Ctrl+F5' in VSCode to run the Pester test file with the suffix '.tests.ps1'.

In 'about_Parsing.Tests.ps1' After you press "Ctrl+F5", the console will directly appear:d:\GitRepository\PowerShell\example\pester\‪about_Parsing\‪about_Parsing.Tests.ps1

The test is then run directly.

How to run tests in such a convenient way and use various `invoke-pester` parameters, such as `-output detailed`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go to the Settings of VSCode and search for Pester, you should find a setting called:

PowerShell > Pester: Output Verbosity

You can set this to "detailed".

The setting also indicates that if you're using Pester v5 or newer you can also set this via the  `$PesterPreference` variable which it uses by default. You could set this variable in your script or PowerShell profile.

```
$PesterPreference = [PesterConfiguration]::Default
$PesterPreference.Output.Verbosity = 'Detailed'
```