# All tests with variables are failing in Pester

Tags: powershell, pester, pester-5

I have started using Pester to write test cases for my `PowerShell` scripts, but unfortunately, I am failing in even simple tests. For any test, if there is a variable in the `It` block the test fails even though it should pass.

Below is a simplified code:

```
Describe 'Basic Pester Tests' {
  It 'A test that should be true' {
    $true | Should -Be $true
  }
}
Describe 'should exist with variables test' {
    $someFile = 'C:\Scripts\EnableFlash.ps1'
    It "$someFile should exist" {
      $someFile | Should -Exist
    }
}

Describe 'should exist without variable test' {
  It "'C:\Scripts\EnableFlash.ps1' should exist" {
    'C:\Scripts\EnableFlash.ps1' | Should -Exist
  }
}

Describe 'compare for addition' {
  $a = 10; $b = 20
  It "test for variables" {
    $($a+$b) | Should -Be 30
  }
}
```

In the above code, the test `should exist with variables test` fails while the test `should exist without variable test` succeeds.

Output:
[image: Output of the script execution]

I am using `PowerShell 5.1` and `Pester 5.1.1`

Comment: In recent Pester versions, variables outside of the `It` are out of scope and cannot be referenced in your test.  You should either place them in the `It` block or define them earlier inside a `BeforeAll`, etc, block..  Some info here: [Discovery and Run](https://pester.dev/docs/usage/discovery-and-run)

Comment: And your next question on how to view the passing tests, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65421454/52598). If it is any consolation, I'm banging my head against the wall myself migrating to pester 5+.

Comment: @boxdog Would you mind submitting your comment as an answer? Just so this doesn't look unanswered anymore :)

Comment: @FrodeF.  I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent Pester versions, variables outside of the `It` are out of scope and cannot be referenced in your test. You should either place them in the `It` block or define them earlier inside a `BeforeAll`, etc, block.

Some info here: [Discovery and Run](https://pester.dev/docs/usage/discovery-and-run)